# Doxygen - Same docstring for multiple method parameters

Tags: c++, doxygen

Suppose you have the following method docstring + declaration:

```
/**\brief What it does
 * \param[in] a docstring for a
 * \param[in] b same docstring as in a
 */
void fun(
    const int& a
    const int& b
    int* c
)
```

Is there a way of making `a` and `b` function parameters have the same docstring without duplicating it?

I tried wrapping them in the `\{ ... \}` syntax, as in functions with same docstring, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried posting to Doxygen [users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/mailman/)?

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? I don't know about you, but I'd be confused if a function took two parameters and both had the *same* documentation. In fact, I'd suspect a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: I don't know about whether it's possible or not but why don't you just create a link to the parameter that has the description you want to reuse using an anchor like this: `See {@link a}`? Also I have to agree with @ChristianHackl - this would be rather confusing. Even if both parameters are of the same type and serve the same purpose (for example: `add(int x, int y)`) you should still at least user their order to distinguish these.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one or more parameters to be described by the same docstring, you can specify them as a comma-separated list. In your case,

```
/**\brief What it does
 * \param[in] a,b some common description
 */
void fun(
    const int& a
    const int& b
    int* c
)
```